# Find monic gcd($x^4+x^3+x+1$, $x^6+x^5+x^4+x+1$) in $\mathbb Z_{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

My working so far using the Euclidean algorithm and polynomial long division (which I won't fully show here)

$x^6+x^5+x^4x+1$ = $(x^2+1) \times (x^4+x^3+x+1) + (-2x^3-x^2)$
and $(-2x^3-x^2) \equiv (x^2)$ in $\mathbb Z_{2}[x]$

So a non-monic gcd would be $x^2$? Should I keep going?

$x^4+x^3+x+1 = (x^2+x) \times (x^2) + (x+1)$

I'm a little confused now - when do I stop?

The answer is supposed to be 1 but I'm not seeing where 1 comes from

Comment: Keep going: $x^2=(x+1)(x+1)+1$

Comment: Hmm, right, I see. But in general how do I know when to stop, is it when I get to a 0 remainder?

Comment: Have you used the Euclidean algorithm for $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}[x]$ before? It's exactly the same algorithm. You stop when you get 0.

Comment: Ah of course.. thank you.

Comment: @Arvin / BK-201: If you found your solution, please post it as an answer to your question so that future readers can benefit from it.

Comment: But coordinators only do things that benefit themselves, Snowball :P   just kidding - 
Answer posted! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wj32 stated, all I needed to do was to keep going one more step:

$x^2=(x+1)(x+1)+1$

$(x+1)^2$ is $(x^2+2x+1)$ but of course $2x \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb Z_{2}$